# Express.js Pug.js | Render the same page after fetch POST request with different content

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a list of article previews that come from a DB and are rendered on the page with a Pug.js mixin.

```
  each article in articles
     +articlePreview(article.title, article.text, article.imgSrc)
```

I would like to enable filtering for these previews (sort by title, filter by category etc.), so I'm sending a fetch POST request to an express application. The route makes the appropriate filtering and should render the same page with the filters applied, but the page is not re-rendering.

In pug I have something like this:

```
        button.filters-btn.filters-title title
            .filters-title-icon
                if (filters.title && filters.title === 'az')
                    span a-z
                else if (filters.title && filters.title === 'za')
                    span z-a
                else 
                    i.arrow.arrow-up 
                    i.arrow.arrow-down
        div(tabindex="0", class="filters-btn filters-category")
            if (filters.category) 
                span= filters.category
                .filters-category-icon
                    button x
            else 
                span category
                .filters-category-icon 
                    i.arrow.arrow-down
            ul(class="filters-category-list")
                li(class=`filters-category-item ${filters.category === 'cooking' ? "filters-category-active" : ''}`) cooking
                li(class=`filters-category-item ${filters.category === 'sport' ? "filters-category-active" : ''}`) sport
                li(class=`filters-category-item ${filters.category === 'travels' ? "filters-category-active" : ''}`) travels
                li(class=`filters-category-item ${filters.category === 'animals' ? "filters-category-active" : ''}`) animals
```

Clicking on one between `.filters-title` or one of the elements of the `.filters-category-list` triggers the fetch call.

In express I simply get the filters from the request, filter the articles and send them back (along with the filters to be shown) via res.render():

```
app.post("/articles", (req, res) => {
  const articles = [...get data from db and apply filters];
  res.render("../articles/index", {
    title: articles,
    articles,
    filters: req.body.filters,
  })
})
```

Should I do this all over again without using pug variables and simply create elements in javascript after express has responded? Or there is a way to make the most of Pug.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are using **fetch** to make the POST request. Fetch is used to make an HTTP without navigating (or **rendering** in your case).

Instead, use **XMLHttpRequest** to post the form:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", write_your_uri_here, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
    value: value
}));
```